# Java try three methods and enter catch block only if none succeeded

Tags: java, try-catch

Try catch block asks to go through steps

```
try {
    step a; 
    step b; 
    step c;
} catch {
    System.out.print("one of the steps failed");
}
```

What if I have plan A, plan B and plan C and I want to try each plan in a row

```
keep.trying{
    plan A; 
    plan B; 
    plan C;
} catch {
    System.out.print("None of the plans worked");
}
```

one can do

```
boolean done=false;
try {
   planA(); 
   done=true;
}catch{// :|}

if (done!=true){
   try {
      planB(); 
      done=true;
   }catch{// :(}

if (done!=true){
   try{
      planC();
   }catch{ System.out.print("Failed"); }

if (done == true){ System.out.print("Success") };
```

---

This is more of a good/bad style question. "try to execute at least one command or throw exception" is a commonplace (try/catch block). Nested "keep.trying" are rarely used. Is this because there is a better style? Or because a program shouldn't produce too much noise (make calls with small success rate)?

Comment: Your description of the actual problem is too vague to give a concrete advice. But if what you want is a more generic solution to the one you have, all you need is a loop that stops as soon as one operation succeeds.

Comment: This smells a bit like you're trying to use exceptions to signal failure from a void method.   If so, that's bad style.   Better style would be to have them return a success/failure flag, even a Boolean, which would make it very easy to chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a method to do that with a bit of lamda usage.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Plan {
    public void execute() throws Exception;
}

public static boolean tryAll(List<Plan> lst) {
    for(Plan p : lst) {
        try {
            p.execute();
            return true; //If we reach this line, p succeeded
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //This plan failed
        }
    }
    return false; //All plans failed
}
```

Alternatively:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Plan {
    public boolean execute();
}

public static boolean tryAll(List<Plan> lst) {
    for(Plan p : lst) {
        if(p.execute()) return true;
    }
    return false; //All plans failed
}
```

Comment: Seems like OP could just have the function return true/false instead of throw exception. if(p.execute){ return true;)}, then return false at end if none of them worked

Comment: That's true as well. From his original code it seemed like "plans" may throw exceptions, but you could easily modify it to use the return value instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here readability of the code is key. This isn't a common pattern. Neither is it a commonplace code.

This situation is rare. So you shouldn't focus on it being concise, rather the code should be clear. So you should write multiple `catch{try{/*do something*/}{catch{try{/*do something else*/...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
   planA;
}
catch
{
   try
   {
       planB;
   }
   catch
   { 
      try
      {
          planC
      }
   }
}
```

I think this is proper way to do this

Comment: I think this is very bad style, because the scoping gets deeper the more plans you have!

Comment: @ loonytune My question is what makes it a bad style and what is a good style? Also, what are the caveats?